# Distributing python app with all dependencies

Tags: python, dependencies, package, pygtk, software-distribution

I need to create an executable python app package containing all dependencies, including  those that cannot be installed using pip (like gtk or other native modules). I must create Linux and Windows versions of this package. The problem is, I cannot find any way to create such package/executable. There are tools like `py2exe` or `cx_Freeze`, but they fail when including `pygtk` and other system dependent modules.

I just cannot believe there is no production ready solution, which allows python developers to do such obvious and trivial tasks.

Comment: I've also encountered a need to create a self-contained archive, similar to JAR, which I can just upload to the target system (there is a bare python2.7) and I want to pack there necessary stuff. Python libs, some external dependencies etc. for all different architectures. Have you resolved it somehow?